# Proper use of db.update with 'whereClause' argument

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-update

As i have discovered, doing raw query does not work well often, and it is not recommended:

```
db.execSQL("update userData set " + hero_whose_score_to_update + "="
+ second_player_score + " where name=" + "'" + getUsername2() + "'");
```

Instead i tried using db.update

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(hero2_whose_score_to_update, second_player_score);
db.update("userData", cv, "where name = ", null);
```

I dont' know exactly how to write it, but i want this:

hero_whose_score_to_update is a string - one of "hero1_score", ..."hero6_score";

second_player_score is int, and it will be some number.

But what is next 2 arguments in update()? whereClause and whereArgs.
I have read the api for update(), but it is still not clear, an example would do much better.

I suspect i should put in whereClause a username,but how should it look?

```
db.update("userData", cv, "where name = 'john'", null);
```

or

```
cv.put("hero3_score", 34) ;
db.update("userData", cv, "where name= ?", 'jonn') ;
```

Comment: Your implementation looks like it's open to [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks

Comment: @LanceJava, thanks, but i m doing an app for school students, security is not an issue

Comment: @LanceJava, just tell me how to update using db.update() method, that is it!

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/ ... LOL

Comment: @LanceJava, apppreciate humor.

Comment: We have no idea how `ContentValues` works or what type `db` is

Comment: db is instance of SQLIteDatabase , contentvalues is just a temporary container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whereClause` is what comes after the WHERE in a raw SQL statement, but without the keyword WHERE.

`whereArgs` is an array of strings, so you have to create such an array:

```
db.update("userData", cv, "name = ?", new String[]{ "jonn" });
```

Comment: i realized the bug was not even about executing sql command, i used db.execSQL() and db.update(). the bug was totally in different area